# Why there is no android database inspector tools in android studio 4.2 canary 13?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm testing Android Studio 4.2 canary 13 and SQLite.

In [this post](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#database-inspector) you can read "*With Android Studio 4.1 Canary 6 **and higher**, you can inspect, query, and modify your app's databases using the new Database Inspector.*" and "*To get started, deploy your app to a device running **API level 26 or higher** and select **View > Tool Windows > Database Inspector** from the menu bar.*", But as you can see in the photo, this option is not available on Android Studio 4.2, Why?

The API of the testing app is 30.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Before using this version of Android Studio(4.2), On my machine(Windows 10 X64) was installed Android Studio 4.0.1, That I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Database Inspector is in App Inspector**

Select View > Tool Windows > App Inspector:
[image: Select View > Tool Windows > App Inspector]

Deploy your app to start using the database inspector:
[image: Deploy your app to start using the database inspector]

Comment: If using `Flutter`, you might want to have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68839489/410996