# Missing Database Inspector in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, sqflite

I have tried to find my Database Inspector in Android Studio in multiple ways, but to no avail:

1. **View → Tool Windows → Database Inspector** is not there
2. **Help → Find Action → Database Inspector** cannot be found with the search function
3. Deleting and re-downloading Android Studio: Error persists

What am I doing wrong?? How can I get my Database Inspector back?

Answer (score 27):

## Missing Android views in Flutter project?

I was working on a Flutter project and the typical Android related views were not present in the list of **View → Tool Windows**:

- App Inspection
- Logcat
- Device File Explorer
- Profiler
- Emulator

For some colleagues they were visible for the same project. When I opened different Android / Flutter projects, they were visible for me too. But not for this particular project. Re-installing Android Studio did not help.

### Solution: Enable the Android Facet

It turned out that I had to enable the Android Facet for this project:

- Go to **File → Project Structure**
- Choose **Facets**
- Press the small **+ Button** at the top
- Select **Android** from the list
- Confirm your project by clicking the **project_name** and press **OK**

This setting is stored locally in the `.idea/project_name.iml`. The .idea folder is excluded from version control in our `.gitignore` file. That is why re-installing did not help and other users had a different experience for the same project.

[image]
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1

Comment: Should be marked as the solution, worked for me today.

Answer (score 9):

On Android Studio Arctic Fox:

`View` > `Tool Windows` > `App inspection`

[image]

Comment: Google just love change for the sake of change